# Why Sales rule (Coupon) not working for variant of virtual configurable product?

Tags: magento-1.7

I created salesrule (coupon) for variant of virtual configurable product, but coupon is not working . Sku of the products variant (variant is as a simple product) - ps_262_549, configurable product skus - ps_262. for ps_262 it is working, but not working for ps_262_549.
[image: Conditions]
[image: Sales rule configuration in admin panel]

But coupon code works for variant of configurable products, if order create via admin panel

Comment: Can you please also share the rule conditions tab?

Comment: Done. Image is in post

Comment: There nothing in conditions

Comment: add the product to the condition and make sure you hit save&apply

Comment: After it,  I get message in my cart: 
"All of the following conditions must be met:
SKU must be ps_262_549."
For ps_262 it is working.. But ps_262_549 (is a variant of ps_262) not. 
From admin panel (when creating order as admin) coupon is OK.

Comment: can you add both the products to the rule and make it any of these conditions.

Comment: it is not working) I check with xdebug, that ps_262_549 is as child for ps_262. Maybe magento not calculate cartrules for child products.?

Comment: It should work for child products also. Do you have any rules with 'stop rules processing' enabled that execute first?

Comment: there are many rules with 'stop rules processing' enabled'. 
And I add to cart, not child product ps_262_549 (This product has option "Not visible individually" ), but ps_262.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override 2 classes: Mage_SalesRule_Model_Quote_Discount and Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator.
in Mage_SalesRule_Model_Quote_Discount you need to comment continue operator
 // continue;  Ignore continue operator

```
public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
{
    parent::collect($address);
    $quote = $address->getQuote();
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore($quote->getStoreId());
    $this->_calculator->reset($address);

    $items = $this->_getAddressItems($address);
    if (!count($items)) {
        return $this;
    }

    $eventArgs = array(
        'website_id'        => $store->getWebsiteId(),
        'customer_group_id' => $quote->getCustomerGroupId(),
        'coupon_code'       => $quote->getCouponCode(),
    );

    $this->_calculator->init($store->getWebsiteId(), $quote->getCustomerGroupId(), $quote->getCouponCode());
    $this->_calculator->initTotals($items, $address);

    $address->setDiscountDescription(array());

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($item->getNoDiscount()) {
            $item->setDiscountAmount(0);
            $item->setBaseDiscountAmount(0);
        }
        else {
            /**
             * Child item discount we calculate for parent
             */
            if ($item->getParentItemId()) {

                // continue;  Ignore continue operator

            }

            $eventArgs['item'] = $item;
            Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_quote_address_discount_item', $eventArgs);

            if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isChildrenCalculated()) {
                foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                    $this->_calculator->process($child);
                    $eventArgs['item'] = $child;
                    Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_quote_address_discount_item', $eventArgs);
                    $this->_aggregateItemDiscount($child);
                }
            } else {
                $this->_calculator->process($item);
                $this->_aggregateItemDiscount($item);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Process shipping amount discount
     */
    $address->setShippingDiscountAmount(0);
    $address->setBaseShippingDiscountAmount(0);
    if ($address->getShippingAmount()) {
        $this->_calculator->processShippingAmount($address);
        $this->_addAmount(-$address->getShippingDiscountAmount());
        $this->_addBaseAmount(-$address->getBaseShippingDiscountAmount());
    }

    $this->_calculator->prepareDescription($address);
    return $this;
}
```

And in Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validatorchange process function:

```
public function process(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract $item)
{
    $item->setDiscountAmount(0);
    $item->setBaseDiscountAmount(0);
    $item->setDiscountPercent(0);

    /** @var $quote Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item*/
    $quote      = $item->getQuote();
    /** @var $address Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Item*/
    $address    = $this->_getAddress($item);

    $itemPrice              = $this->_getItemPrice($item);
    $baseItemPrice          = $this->_getItemBasePrice($item);
    $itemOriginalPrice      = $this->_getItemOriginalPrice($item);
    $baseItemOriginalPrice  = $this->_getItemBaseOriginalPrice($item);

    if ($item->getParentItemId()) {
        $parent = $item->getParentItem();

        $itemPrice = $this->_getItemPrice($parent);
        $baseItemPrice = $this->_getItemBasePrice($parent);
        $itemOriginalPrice = $this->_getItemOriginalPrice($parent);
        $baseItemOriginalPrice = $this->_getItemBaseOriginalPrice($parent);
    }

    if ($itemPrice < 0) {
        return $this;
    }

    $appliedRuleIds = array();
    foreach ($this->_getRules() as $rule) {
        /* @var $rule Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule */
        if (!$this->_canProcessRule($rule, $address)) {
            continue;
        }

        if (!$rule->getActions()->validate($item)) {
            continue;
        }

        $qty = $this->_getItemQty($item, $rule);
        $rulePercent = min(100, $rule->getDiscountAmount());

        $discountAmount = 0;
        $baseDiscountAmount = 0;
        //discount for original price
        $originalDiscountAmount = 0;
        $baseOriginalDiscountAmount = 0;

        switch ($rule->getSimpleAction()) {
            case Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::TO_PERCENT_ACTION:
                $rulePercent = max(0, 100-$rule->getDiscountAmount());
            //no break;
            case Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::BY_PERCENT_ACTION:
                $step = $rule->getDiscountStep();
                if ($step) {
                    $qty = floor($qty/$step)*$step;
                }
                $_rulePct = $rulePercent/100;
                $discountAmount    = ($qty*$itemPrice - $item->getDiscountAmount()) * $_rulePct;
                $baseDiscountAmount= ($qty*$baseItemPrice - $item->getBaseDiscountAmount()) * $_rulePct;
                //get discount for original price
                $originalDiscountAmount    = ($qty*$itemOriginalPrice - $item->getDiscountAmount()) * $_rulePct;
                $baseOriginalDiscountAmount= ($qty*$baseItemOriginalPrice - $item->getDiscountAmount()) * $_rulePct;

                if (!$rule->getDiscountQty() || $rule->getDiscountQty()>$qty) {
                    $discountPercent = min(100, $item->getDiscountPercent()+$rulePercent);
                    $item->setDiscountPercent($discountPercent);
                }
                break;
            case Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::TO_FIXED_ACTION:
                $quoteAmount = $quote->getStore()->convertPrice($rule->getDiscountAmount());
                $discountAmount    = $qty*($itemPrice-$quoteAmount);
                $baseDiscountAmount= $qty*($baseItemPrice-$rule->getDiscountAmount());
                //get discount for original price
                $originalDiscountAmount    = $qty*($itemOriginalPrice-$quoteAmount);
                $baseOriginalDiscountAmount= $qty*($baseItemOriginalPrice-$rule->getDiscountAmount());
                break;

            case Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::BY_FIXED_ACTION:
                $step = $rule->getDiscountStep();
                if ($step) {
                    $qty = floor($qty/$step)*$step;
                }
                $quoteAmount        = $quote->getStore()->convertPrice($rule->getDiscountAmount());
                $discountAmount     = $qty*$quoteAmount;
                $baseDiscountAmount = $qty*$rule->getDiscountAmount();
                break;

            case Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::CART_FIXED_ACTION:
                if (empty($this->_rulesItemTotals[$rule->getId()])) {
                    Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Item totals are not set for rule.'));
                }

                /**
                 * prevent applying whole cart discount for every shipping order, but only for first order
                 */
                if ($quote->getIsMultiShipping()) {
                    $usedForAddressId = $this->getCartFixedRuleUsedForAddress($rule->getId());
                    if ($usedForAddressId && $usedForAddressId != $address->getId()) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        $this->setCartFixedRuleUsedForAddress($rule->getId(), $address->getId());
                    }
                }
                $cartRules = $address->getCartFixedRules();
                if (!isset($cartRules[$rule->getId()])) {
                    $cartRules[$rule->getId()] = $rule->getDiscountAmount();
                }

                if ($cartRules[$rule->getId()] > 0) {
                    if ($this->_rulesItemTotals[$rule->getId()]['items_count'] <= 1) {
                        $quoteAmount = $quote->getStore()->convertPrice($cartRules[$rule->getId()]);
                        $baseDiscountAmount = min($baseItemPrice * $qty, $cartRules[$rule->getId()]);
                    } else {
                        $discountRate = $baseItemPrice * $qty /
                                        $this->_rulesItemTotals[$rule->getId()]['base_items_price'];
                        $maximumItemDiscount = $rule->getDiscountAmount() * $discountRate;
                        $quoteAmount = $quote->getStore()->convertPrice($maximumItemDiscount);

                        $baseDiscountAmount = min($baseItemPrice * $qty, $maximumItemDiscount);
                        $this->_rulesItemTotals[$rule->getId()]['items_count']--;
                    }

                    $discountAmount = min($itemPrice * $qty, $quoteAmount);
                    $discountAmount = $quote->getStore()->roundPrice($discountAmount);
                    $baseDiscountAmount = $quote->getStore()->roundPrice($baseDiscountAmount);

                    //get discount for original price
                    $originalDiscountAmount = min($itemOriginalPrice * $qty, $quoteAmount);
                    $baseOriginalDiscountAmount = $quote->getStore()->roundPrice($originalDiscountAmount);
                    $baseOriginalDiscountAmount = $quote->getStore()->roundPrice($baseItemOriginalPrice);

                    $cartRules[$rule->getId()] -= $baseDiscountAmount;
                }
                $address->setCartFixedRules($cartRules);

                break;

            case Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::BUY_X_GET_Y_ACTION:
                $x = $rule->getDiscountStep();
                $y = $rule->getDiscountAmount();
                if (!$x || $y > $x) {
                    break;
                }
                $buyAndDiscountQty = $x + $y;

                $fullRuleQtyPeriod = floor($qty / $buyAndDiscountQty);
                $freeQty  = $qty - $fullRuleQtyPeriod * $buyAndDiscountQty;

                $discountQty = $fullRuleQtyPeriod * $y;
                if ($freeQty > $x) {
                    $discountQty += $freeQty - $x;
                }

                $discountAmount    = $discountQty * $itemPrice;
                $baseDiscountAmount= $discountQty * $baseItemPrice;
                //get discount for original price
                $originalDiscountAmount    = $discountQty * $itemOriginalPrice;
                $baseOriginalDiscountAmount= $discountQty * $baseItemOriginalPrice;
                break;
        }

        $result = new Varien_Object(array(
            'discount_amount'      => $discountAmount,
            'base_discount_amount' => $baseDiscountAmount,
        ));
        Mage::dispatchEvent('salesrule_validator_process', array(
            'rule'    => $rule,
            'item'    => $item,
            'address' => $address,
            'quote'   => $quote,
            'qty'     => $qty,
            'result'  => $result,
        ));

        $discountAmount = $result->getDiscountAmount();
        $baseDiscountAmount = $result->getBaseDiscountAmount();

        $percentKey = $item->getDiscountPercent();
        /**
         * Process "delta" rounding
         */
        if ($percentKey) {
            $delta      = isset($this->_roundingDeltas[$percentKey]) ? $this->_roundingDeltas[$percentKey] : 0;
            $baseDelta  = isset($this->_baseRoundingDeltas[$percentKey])
                    ? $this->_baseRoundingDeltas[$percentKey]
                    : 0;
            $discountAmount+= $delta;
            $baseDiscountAmount+=$baseDelta;

            $this->_roundingDeltas[$percentKey]     = $discountAmount -
                                                      $quote->getStore()->roundPrice($discountAmount);
            $this->_baseRoundingDeltas[$percentKey] = $baseDiscountAmount -
                                                      $quote->getStore()->roundPrice($baseDiscountAmount);
            $discountAmount = $quote->getStore()->roundPrice($discountAmount);
            $baseDiscountAmount = $quote->getStore()->roundPrice($baseDiscountAmount);
        } else {
            $discountAmount     = $quote->getStore()->roundPrice($discountAmount);
            $baseDiscountAmount = $quote->getStore()->roundPrice($baseDiscountAmount);
        }

        /**
         * We can't use row total here because row total not include tax
         * Discount can be applied on price included tax
         */

        $itemDiscountAmount = $item->getDiscountAmount();
        $itemBaseDiscountAmount = $item->getBaseDiscountAmount();

        $discountAmount     = min($itemDiscountAmount + $discountAmount, $itemPrice * $qty);

        $baseDiscountAmount = min($itemBaseDiscountAmount + $baseDiscountAmount, $baseItemPrice * $qty);


        if ($item->getParentItemId()) {
            $parent = $item->getParentItem();

            $parent->setDiscountAmount($discountAmount);
            $parent->setBaseDiscountAmount($baseDiscountAmount);

            $parent->setOriginalDiscountAmount($originalDiscountAmount);
            $parent->setBaseOriginalDiscountAmount($baseOriginalDiscountAmount);

            $appliedRuleIds[$rule->getRuleId()] = $rule->getRuleId();

            $parent->setAppliedRuleIds(join(',',$appliedRuleIds));
        }

        $item->setDiscountAmount($discountAmount);
        $item->setBaseDiscountAmount($baseDiscountAmount);

        $item->setOriginalDiscountAmount($originalDiscountAmount);
        $item->setBaseOriginalDiscountAmount($baseOriginalDiscountAmount);


        $appliedRuleIds[$rule->getRuleId()] = $rule->getRuleId();

        $this->_maintainAddressCouponCode($address, $rule);
        $this->_addDiscountDescription($address, $rule);

        if ($rule->getStopRulesProcessing()) {
            break;
        }
    }

    $item->setAppliedRuleIds(join(',',$appliedRuleIds));
    $address->setAppliedRuleIds($this->mergeIds($address->getAppliedRuleIds(), $appliedRuleIds));
    $quote->setAppliedRuleIds($this->mergeIds($quote->getAppliedRuleIds(), $appliedRuleIds));

    return $this;
}
```